# How can I create animated scrollable bottomsheet in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I would like to create a scroll up bottomsheet something like this

[image: something like this]

Right now I am working with DraggableScrollableSheet widget. But I don't know how to add animation and that handle icon that changes when the sheet goes up or down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  `Solid bottom sheet` package from [here](https://pub.dev/packages/solid_bottom_sheet)

also [bottom_sheet_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/bottom_sheet_bar) is similar like this.

Comment: quick question, I am using like 18 packages for my flutter app. is using too many packages bad?

Comment: No problem brother. 
But if you can make something easily then don't use package.

Answer (score 0):

In my flutter projects I use the following package for animated bottom sheets:

https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet